Using pdfjs in Sveltekit/Typescript
I need to use pdfjs (current 4.1.392) for text extraction in a sveltekit 4 typescript project. This is how I try to import pdfjs into my src/routes/+page.svelte:
<script lang="ts">
import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf';
import pdfjsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker';
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;
</script>

However, I get the error message "Invalid 'workerSrc' type".
How can I use pdfjs in sveltekit/typescript?

The following code works for me with pdfjs-dist 4.2.67, svelte 4.2.15 and typescript 5.4.5:
<script lang="ts">
  // @ts-nocheck
  import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist';
  import * as pdfWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs';
  pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = import.meta.url + 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs';
</script>


You can try to do something like this:
import * as pdfjs from "pdfjs-dist";
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs", import.meta.url);

For more use examples, you can visit PDF.js Github repository:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#online-demo

Thanks! pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc is of type string, so this throws an exception. If I use pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = import.meta.url + 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs'; instead (correctly resulting in http://localhost:5173/src/routes/+page.svelte?t=1713774742738pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs), I will get a warning from pdfjs.getDocument() "Setting up fake worker" and eventually two exceptions ("document is not defined" and "Setting up fake worker failed: "WorkerMessageHandler" is undefined).
